# Apiman (RedHat) and OpenAM (forgerock)

Tags: oauth, openam, apiman

Is it possible to use Apiman over OpenAM infrastructure with OAuth2. Apiman is working with keycloak (RedHat) authentication solution, but can we replace kaycloak with OpenAM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm not hugely familiar with OpenAM. I've just had a quick scan of their documentation, and it seems to use the same basic set of technologies (OpenID Connect with JWT) as Keycloak.

So, the first thing I'd suggest is that you try your luck; see if you can get OpenAM's tokens working with the existing Keycloak OAuth2 plugin.

Failing that, you may need to write your own apiman plugin to support OpenAM (which is pretty easy, thankfully) - see:

- [Plugins repository on GitHub](https://github.com/apiman/apiman-plugins)
- [Plugin author's guide](http://www.apiman.io/latest/developer-guide.html#_creating_a_plugin)

It might also be worth filing a JIRA ticket which would help us gauge demand for specific support (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/APIMAN/).